# How to sum bars that are more than 103 back in history?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to sum a bars' varible `propVolume` back since the one which `bar_index` I specify via input settings. It works just fine unless I give it `bar_index` of a bar, which is farer than 103 bars back. In documentation they say that that may be due to shortage of default buffer for `time` built-in variable, which is used my `bar_index` internally, they advise to call `max_bars_back` function to extend that buffer for `time` built-in, I did that, but it didn't help. Same problem persist - no more than 103 bars back in the history. Here is the snippet. Any ideas on overcoming 103 limit for history are much appreciated. Thank you!

```
//@version=5
// Declaration Statement
int MAX_BARS = 1000
indicator("Volume by Rang1e", "Volume by Range1", format = format.volume, overlay = false , max_labels_count = 500, max_bars_back = MAX_BARS)

enter code here
// Inputs 
int anchorInput = input.int(20000, "Anchor", 1, 100000, 1, "Anchor tooltip")
max_bars_back(time, MAX_BARS)
int n_bars = nz(ta.barssince(bar_index[1] == anchorInput) + 1, 1)
float propVolume = volume / 2 //Whatever...
float totalPropVolume = math.sum(propVolume[1], n_bars) 
plot(totalPropVolume, color = color.green, style = plot.style_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to sum the number of bars in history.

```
// Declaration Statement
indicator("Volume by Rang1e", "Volume by Range1", format = format.volume, overlay = false , max_labels_count = 500, max_bars_back = MAX_BARS)

// Inputs 
int anchorInput = input.int(20000, "Anchor", 1, 100000, 1, "Anchor tooltip")

float propVolume = volume / 2
float totalPropVolume = math.sum(propVolume[1], anchorInput) 
plot(totalPropVolume, color = color.green, style = plot.style_columns)
```

Comment: Hi, John. Thank you for looking into my question. The code above unfortunately also abuts into that strange limit of 103 bars back in history. Also, what it does is sum of bars form 0 to anchorInput, whereas I need form anchorInput + 1 to current one

Comment: i added a prior comment, check that one out

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that the problem is that `math.sum()` does not like to get its `length` parameter as varying variable. This code will make a trouble:

```
int n_bars = nz(ta.barssince(bar_index[1] == anchorInput) + 1, 1) // Problem!!! It would not be a problem if `int n_bars = 1000` be a const   
float totalPropVolume = math.sum(propVolume[1], n_bars)
```

If you do not change your `n_bars` from one bar to another - it works just fine, but if you need to vary the quantity of bars back to sum - then you will encounter this issue. My quess is that you will face same problem with all the built-in functions alike.

I worked around the issue by removing built-in right away from code and utilizing global variable:

```
// Declaration Statement
indicator("Volume by Range2", "Volume by Range2", format = format.volume, overlay = false , max_labels_count = 100)

// Inputs 
int anchorInput = input.int(20000, "Anchor", 1, 100000, 1, "Anchor tooltip")

var float totalPropVolume = 0 // Global for keeping cummulative value
float propVolume =  volume / 2 // Whatever value you want to sum
totalPropVolume := bar_index > anchorInput ? totalPropVolume + propVolume: 0 // Cummulate starting the anchor bar you speciafy via settings of the indicator
bColor = totalPropVolume > 0 ? color.green : color.red
plot(totalPropVolume, color = bColor, style = plot.style_columns)
```

I find this code even more clean and clear.

Comment: how large do you expect n_bars to be? there are two ways to address this problem, one way is to estimate the maximum n_bars, the other way is to calculate the bars to start summing using your anchor input value. 

```var n_bars =math.max(1,last_bar_index - anchorInput)```